# Best way to generate file names automatically in s3 using python

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, doc2vec

I have a python script and in that i am building a doc2vec model and saving it to s3 with different version names.
see the screenshot for reference

[image]

Now the data in my database gets updated weekly once and i need to re-build the doc2vec model including the new data.

For this I have scheduled a script in AWS lambda to run the python script weekly once.

Now i want to save the model into s3 with model_name starting with "model_d2v_version_008" this week and then "model_d2v_version_009" next week and so on likewise every week.

I used to provide the model_name before automating the process

```
def d2v_doc(titles_df):
    tagged_data = [TaggedDocument(words=_d, tags=[str(titles_df['id_titles'][i])]) for i, _d in enumerate(titles_df['doc'])]
    model_d2v = Doc2Vec(vector_size=300,min_count=10, dm=1)
    model_d2v.build_vocab(tagged_data)
    model_d2v.train(tagged_data,epochs=100,total_examples=model_d2v.corpus_count)
    return model_d2v

def save_d2v_to_s3(model,fname):
    model_name = fname
    joblib.dump(model,model_name)
    s3_base_path='s3://sd-flikku/datalake/doc2vec_model'
    path = s3_base_path+'/'+model_name
    command = "aws s3 cp {} {}".format(model_name,path).split()
    print('saving...'+model_name)
    subprocess.call(command)


model_doc = d2v_doc(titles_df)

save_d2v_to_s3(model_doc,"model_d2v_version_007")
```

Now as the process is automated i want the model_names to stay the same format and increase the count of the version every week. How can i do that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you specifically need an incrementing number? Does the number mean anything important? If not, I'd recommend generating a unique name (UUID) or perhaps simply basing it on the date (which has the additional benefit of conveying some information in the name). Both options will avoid name clashes, and you won't need a database to track the most-recently used number.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein there is reason behind using the version numbers. One thing for sure the naming convention is pretty easy to understand and other thing is i can keep track of performance of my models and i can choose the best model with high accuracy later on.

Comment: I would suggest using `YYYYMMDD` date format in the name. They will sort just as well, and will provide a concept of when they were created. More meaningful than just `+1` number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a suffix or prefix of `YYYYMMDD`, as suggested by @john-rotenstein in the comment, would be a really robust choice, typical of wise professional programmers.

It encodes extra useful information. If failures or exceptional situations occasionally happen, making one run happen later, early, or never, they still sort into the right order, with some hints about the deviation which occurred. ("Oh, 20200719 is missing. Wasn't that the week of the meteor strike?")

If the system lives longer than expected, or moves to an accelerated schedule (as long as it's still no more than once per day), they still sort in the right order. (Numbers of the form `007` stop sorting in a useful way when they reach `1000`.)

If you do expect to create more than one model per day, you could use a suffix down to the minute or second (`YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`, perhaps even with a trailing 'Z' to hint UTC), for example for right now `'model_d2v_version_20200518183227Z'`.

If you need a count of all versions using just the AWS bucket info, it requires the same iteration-over-keys as any other numbering (to reach the last item), while making other useful info (earliest, latest) vivid in the filenames.

Making a new save requires no other information than an accurate system date. (And, while clock errors can lead to all sorts of hairy bugs, nowadays a system that's able to read/write to S3 will almost always have a reliable date.) Ensuring you're not inadvertently reusing a name, and thus perhaps clobbering a prior run, requires the exact same amount of checking. (Though, if there's a risk of multiple systems/processes attempting the same action in a near-simultaneous/interleaved fashion, there's still tiny windows of risk.)

On the other hand, if you really want to use a simple fixed-width incrementing version number, store the last-used number somewhere. When you need a new name...

```
this_version = last_version + 1
model_name = 'model_d2v_version_{0:03d}'.format(this_version)
# then store this_version somewhere you can read it into last_version later
```

But the date/timestamp-based naming is way better:

```
from datetime import datetime
model_name = 'model_d2v_version_' + datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%SZ')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer, it really helped me solve the issue.